# Problem Implementing Observer Pattern : "Member reference base type ________ is not a structure or union"

Tags: c++, list, templates, iterator, observer-pattern

I've been implementing a barebones observer pattern and am stuck on a somewhat cryptic error:
"Member reference base type 'Observer *' is not a structure or union". I assume this has something to do with my use of templates, with which I'm still fairly uncomfortable. Here is the offending code (most cons/destructors removed to simplify things):

Subject interface:

```
class Subject { 
public:
    virtual void notify();
private:
    list< Observer * > m_observers; 
};
```

Subject implementation:

```
void Subject::notify() {
    list< Observer * >::iterator i;

    for ( i = m_observers.begin(); i != m_observers.end(); i++ ) {
        *i->update( this );                        // ERROR !!! ERROR
}
```

Observer abstract interface:

```
class Observer {
public:
    virtual ~Observer();
    virtual void update( Subject * changedSubject ) = 0;

protected:
    Observer();
};
```

Concrete Observer interface:

```
class ConcreteObserver: public Observer {

public:
    ConcreteObserver( ConcreteSubject * );
    virtual ~ConcreteObserver();

    virtual void update( Subject * changedSubject );

private:
    ConcreteSubject * m_subject;
};
```

Concrete Observer implementation:

```
void ConcreteObserver::update( Subject * changedSubject ) {
    if ( changedSubject == m_subject ) {
        report();
    }
}
```

If anyone could help identify this problem, I would greatly appreciate it.

Cheers,
Nick

Comment: did you try `(*i)->update( this );`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is with the operator precedence. Instead of:

```
*i->update( this );
```

Use:

```
(*i)->update( this );
```

Otherwise, it will be interpreted as `*(i->update( this ))`, which tries to call a method on a pointer, resulting in the error message.

Comment: Ahhhh. Thanks interjay, works great. I remember this now, from a comp sci lecture way back when. Should stick better this time.

Comment: Me too, I was passing an object by reference and when I tried to set one its properties I got the error above. So *referencedObject.name = @"Bruce" got an error, (*referencedObject).name = @"Bruce" is fine. Actually, no, the error I got was "Semantic Issue: Member reference base type 'GoodClass *__autoreleasing *' is not a structure or union". But the solution works nonetheless.