# Member reference base type 'int' is not a structure or union

Tags: c++, xcode, int

I have the following code:

```
void setup()
{
address_t sp, pc;

sp = (address_t)stack1 + STACK_SIZE - sizeof(address_t);
pc = (address_t)f;


sigsetjmp(jbuf[0],1);
(jbuf[0]->__jmpbuf)[JB_SP] = translate_address(sp);<----ERROR
(jbuf[0]->__jmpbuf)[JB_PC] = translate_address(pc);<----ERROR
sigemptyset(&jbuf[0]->__saved_mask);<----ERROR     


sp = (address_t)stack2 + STACK_SIZE - sizeof(address_t);
pc = (address_t)g;

sigsetjmp(jbuf[1],1);
(jbuf[1]->__jmpbuf)[JB_SP] = translate_address(sp);<----ERROR
(jbuf[1]->__jmpbuf)[JB_PC] = translate_address(pc);<----ERROR
sigemptyset(&jbuf[1]->__saved_mask);<----ERROR

}
```

Any idea of what this error means?

Comment: If you're thinking it is safe and/or portable to mess with the stack pointer (SP) or program counter (PC) like that, you need to think again.

Comment: This post seems related:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683451

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of a `sigjmp_buf` (which is what `sigsetjmp()` takes as a first parameter) is opaque — it's not what your code is expecting it to be in this case.  Apparently, it's a simple `int` here, not a pointer to a struct.

If you want to muck around with the internals of the `sigjmp_buf`, you'll need to look into how it's implemented on that particular platform (and obviously the code will not be portable).